# How do I correctly get swash shape for CronosPro using FontPro?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, minionpro, swash

I discovered that my CronosPro doesn't support `\textsw` when using MyriadPro's `crswash` option.

My CronosPro*.otf are fine with swash shape even in Pages
[image: Pages Result]

Yet I can't get the shape in LaTeX, even though MinionPro (which I installed using FontPro in the same way) could:

[image: No swash shape]

I tried reinstalling CronosPro but it still didn't work. Is there anything particular for installing CronosPro using FontPro that I could do?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you want to use advanced otf features, you should use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX with [`fontspec`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf). Chapter 2 of the manual is on "OpenType font features".